# Does Visual Studio Community support "Add as Link"?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio

When I try to add a file from another project as a link to my project, by using Project > Add existing file, the "Add as link" little black drop down arrow next to "Add" command is missing.

Comment: What kind of project are you working on?  Apparently this is a [known issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Tooling/issues/147) for ASP.NET 5 projects.

Comment: I open my VB.NET Web App project and want to add a link to an existing file in my VB.NET Windows App project.

Comment: I've just verified on my copy of VS Community and it does indeed support the "Add as Link" option.  That doesn't explain why you're not seeing it, though.  Have you tried it with other project types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does support "Add as Link".

PROBLEM:
My Visual Basic .NET project was a "web site" which doesn't have feature "Add as Link".

SOLUTION:
VB.NET web app project supports "Add as Link".